# Javascript add on click event to input submit field

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a javascript click event to an input field as shown below. Have tried multiple things such as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("search-submit").addEventListener("click", function () { do something})
```

I am not able to add an id to the input field, so I will have to grasp the element by class.

```html
<div class="nv-nav-search" aria-label="search">
  <div class="form-wrap ">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://www.k.nl/"><label><span class="screen-reader-text">Zoek naar...</span><input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoek naar..." value="" name="s"></label><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
      <div class="nv-search-icon-wrap">
        <div class="nv-icon nv-search">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1216 832q0-185-131.5-316.5t-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5 316.5-131.5 131.5-316.5zm512 832q0 52-38 90t-90 38q-54 0-90-38l-343-342q-179 124-399 124-143 0-273.5-55.5t-225-150-150-225-55.5-273.5 55.5-273.5 150-225 225-150 273.5-55.5 273.5 55.5 225 150 150 225 55.5 273.5q0 220-124 399l343 343q37 37 37 90z"></path></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to send the user to a different url with the input which is given. The problem is one can mouse click or can click enter to perform the submit action.

Comment: Did you try the mdn doc, this should be simple !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why instead of use button `click` don't use `submit event` on form like:

```js
document.querySelector(".search-form").addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(document.querySelector('.search-field').value);
});
```

```html
<div class="nv-nav-search" aria-label="search">
  <div class="form-wrap ">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://www.k.nl/"><label><span class="screen-reader-text">Zoek naar...</span><input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoek naar..." value="" name="s"></label><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
      <div class="nv-search-icon-wrap">
        <div class="nv-icon nv-search">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1216 832q0-185-131.5-316.5t-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5 316.5-131.5 131.5-316.5zm512 832q0 52-38 90t-90 38q-54 0-90-38l-343-342q-179 124-399 124-143 0-273.5-55.5t-225-150-150-225-55.5-273.5 55.5-273.5 150-225 225-150 273.5-55.5 273.5 55.5 225 150 150 225 55.5 273.5q0 220-124 399l343 343q37 37 37 90z"></path></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow great this does the trick! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, acept this as answer for the community :)

Comment: Do have one more questions. My script is not working on mobile:

document.querySelector(".search-form").addEventListener("submit", redirect);
   alert("mobile1");
  
  function redirect(e) {
   alert("mobile2");
   e.preventDefault();
   var searchvalue = document.querySelector('.search-field').value;
   window.location.href = "/?s=" + searchvalue + "&post_type=product";
  }

alert 2 is not working @SimoneRossaini

Comment: It has something to do with ES6 not being supported, but not sure how to convert it to ES5. Have tried "use strict";

Comment: i tested your code work as expect.. have you a live preview?

Comment: Well it does work on desktop but not on mobile. What I understand now is that submit event is not the one I need as mobile doesn't know this. Have tried touchend but same result.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByClassName("search-submit")` **returns an array of elements and not a single element**. You need to structure your code as shown below to get it working.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("search-submit")[0].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('clicked me!');
})
```

```html
<div class="nv-nav-search" aria-label="search">
  <div class="form-wrap ">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://www.k.nl/"><label><span class="screen-reader-text">Zoek naar...</span><input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoek naar..." value="" name="s"></label><input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search">
      <div class="nv-search-icon-wrap">
        <div class="nv-icon nv-search">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1216 832q0-185-131.5-316.5t-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5 316.5-131.5 131.5-316.5zm512 832q0 52-38 90t-90 38q-54 0-90-38l-343-342q-179 124-399 124-143 0-273.5-55.5t-225-150-150-225-55.5-273.5 55.5-273.5 150-225 225-150 273.5-55.5 273.5 55.5 225 150 150 225 55.5 273.5q0 220-124 399l343 343q37 37 37 90z"></path></svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**getElements**ByClassName returns a list. If you are sure your list is non empty, select the first one:

`document.getElementsByClassName("search-submit")[0].`

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you are not making a reference to the index of the HTML collection you have queried using getElementsByClassName. This returns a collection of HTML elements. I personally prefer using querySelectorAll('.classname'), this returns an array like nodeList which can be iterated over using forEach.

You iterate over the nodeList and use a ***unique class*** selector to identify the button being pressed. In your case we can use its class `.search-submit`, though you could use an parent selector as well. This will work regardless of ***clicking*** the event or pressing the ***enter*** button. This will make the whole thing a bit more dynamic by not having to reference the ***index*** of the ***selectors*** ***node*** as you may have multiple buttons in your form with the same class selector.

Further explanation found in code below.

```js
// make a constant and assign a nodeList using querySelectorAll()
const searchesBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".search-submit")

// the event callback function passing in the event.target
function searchEvent(e) {
  // do something with the event
  console.log('your search input event has fired')
}

// take the nodeList and iterate over the nodes 
// check the elements classList and make sure it contains 
// the 'unique-class' class
searchesBtn.forEach(search => {
  if (search.classList.contains('unique-class')) {
    // the event is the search button run the function on click
    search.addEventListener('click', searchEvent)
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="nv-nav-search" aria-label="search">
  <div class="form-wrap ">
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="https://www.k.nl/">
      <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text">Zoek naar...</span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Zoek naar..." value="" name="s">
      </label>
      <input type="submit" class="search-submit unique-class" value="Search">
      <div class="nv-search-icon-wrap">
        <div class="nv-icon nv-search">
          <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M1216 832q0-185-131.5-316.5t-316.5-131.5-316.5 131.5-131.5 316.5 131.5 316.5 316.5 131.5 316.5-131.5 131.5-316.5zm512 832q0 52-38 90t-90 38q-54 0-90-38l-343-342q-179 124-399 124-143 0-273.5-55.5t-225-150-150-225-55.5-273.5 55.5-273.5 150-225 225-150 273.5-55.5 273.5 55.5 225 150 150 225 55.5 273.5q0 220-124 399l343 343q37 37 37 90z"></path>
          </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```